# Load Mathematica packages from the network

Tags: packages, networking

Is it possible to load packages (.m) directly from the network (http, https) without installing it locally?

Comment: Do you mean load from the world wide web via ftp ? Or did you mean how to store a package in an html page and load it via the hypertext transport protocol ( http) ?

Comment: Could also be ftp. I would however prefer http to transfer .m file as it is and be loaded as a package. The goal is to have a package used by several users during a development when the package changes very frequently without using synchronization tools like Dropbox, wget or Mathematica URL tools.

Comment: Would your best approach be to store this in a git or mercurial repository and some sort of change tracking as is the normal practise for multi-person development projects? You could then have a few Mathematica functions to pull/push the package to your local repository.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Yes I would like the users to pull the file from the depository but for some reasons I should not install additional tools to their system. So, only plain Mathematica functions. After being unlucky with Needs[], it now looks that simple Import["https://.../package.m"] loads the file and namespace just OK. Can anyone explain me the difference between the Needs[] and Import[] of .m files?

Comment: Glad you found a solution to your problem. `Needs` checks to see if the context you are requesting is already in `$Packages` and calls `Get`, i.e. has already been loaded. `Import` reads all types of files into Mathematica but will not perform the checks that `Needs` does in the case of package files.

Comment: @image_doctor and boocko: May I suggest that one of you provides the above as a canonical answer for other users to pick up?

Comment: So in the case of loading .m files `Import` is just the same as `Get`, except the `Get` reads local while the `Import` can read remotely?

Comment: A simple `Import` command is the same as using `Get`. If you need it, `Import` also offers you the additional feature of being able to import specific elements of your `.m` file as detailed here http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/Package.html

Comment: @Boocko as SjoerdC.deVries suggests, you could, if you wanted,  provide an answer to your own question with the solution you have arrived at.

Answer (score 6):

When loading packages *remotely* in Mathematica (extension `.m`) one can use the `Import` function, which behaves just as `Get`. However, one must the manually check the need for loading packages (something that is usually dome with `Needs`).

It is possible to use `Import` also within the imported package.

In the examples below one loads package `Test` using `Import["https://.../Test1.m"]`, which automatically loads `Test2.m` and imports both `Test'` and `Test'Deeptest'` namespaces and both funcions `firstF` and `secondF`.

File `Test1.m`, placed somewhere on the WWW server.

```
    Import["https://.../Test2.m"]
    BeginPackage["Test`"]
      firstF::usage = "firstF[] calls secondF[] and prepends word first"
    Begin["`Private`"]
      firstF[] := "first, " <> Test`DeepTest`secondF[]
    End[ ]
    EndPackage[ ]
```

File `Test2.m`, placed somewhere on the WWW server.

```
    BeginPackage["Test`DeepTest`"]
     secondF::usage = "secondF[] returns string second"
    Begin["`Private`"]
     secondF[] := "second"
    End[ ]
    EndPackage[ ]
```

Thanks to the image_doctor for providing the initial help.

Answer (score 1):

For an enterprise deployment of a package we store our packages on a network file server and then add the following to the user's init.m file:

```
AppendTo[$Path,"pathToOurPackages"];
PacletManager`PacletDirectoryAdd["pathToOurPackages"]
```

You can then use `Needs` and package documentation shows up in the help browser.

For development we have found it to be much easier to use Wolfram Workbench (we use the Eclipse plugin) to synchronize with a Git archive (over http or other protocols) and load the package into Mathematica. It has a big advantage of automatically clearing and reloading the package after you make changes.